# Cloning a Hard drive to avoid re-installing OS and other programs

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, operating-systems, disk-cloning

I guess , its been a long time since I did this but I have a HDD whose S.M.A.R.T readings report a "imminent failure" . Its an Apple HDD so I thought it'd long lasting  when I bought it but alas - not all good things last. What I want do is Clone it perfectly so as to avoid re-installing the OS and all Apps. Now I know you can use Symantec Ghost and similar s/w but my question is WILL it do perfect clone so as to make the previous OS install and other apps "transparent" OR the previous hard drive ID numbers are stored and doing a clone is NOT going to avoid a fresh re-install. To make matters worse its got a LINUX and W7 partition. I dont really want to LINUX partition - I can download a new version and re-install - I am worried about windows 7 . If the answer is NO- is there a technique where I can "migrate " this install to the new HDD to avoid all other  Licensed programs from being re-installed or these other programs are also HDD specific ?

Comment: There are many products out there, do some research and try them out... for what it's worth, If you want a sector-by-sector copy of your disk then I'd use `dd` available on almost all Linux flavours. CloneZilla is such a solution but has much more utilities. `dd` is the slowest but doesn't care about partitions as it takes sector data rather than trying to identify partitions and partition types/file systems.

Comment: David Brook's answer is the one, but I just thought I'd mention that only Windows will cause you licensing issues. Apple software is tied to the user not the machine, Windows is tied to the machine, so cloning to another drive *may* require you to re-authenticate with Microsoft. Other than that, there should be no issues with David's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be Carbon Copy Cloner (probably number 1 on my absolutely-must-have list). You could also try CloneZilla, SuperDuper! or another rsync-based app (there are a few out there). I've tried most of them and keep coming back to CCC. If it ain't broke don't fix it! I've used CCC to restore to a freshly partitiined drive more times than I care to count so I know it works well..

Many or most of the above are either free or have a trial period.

As to Linux - probably a rsync option is available but you could always reinstall it Windows? Winclone ought to work. A bit of work to back up 3 partitions but hey, the disk-drive Gods already hate you it seems...

D

Comment: CC cloner and Winclone seem to come out as some obvious choices.. back for the windows install would I have to to re-authenticate with license key or this will  do the job to  the end.     Thank you very much.